# A Simple Word Game

Tags: word, word-property

This is a simple little word game I devised, that may require a little out-of-the-box thinking. I'll give you a few examples of my rule:

> The = 44
>   Boombox = 28
>   Gothic = 56
>   Hopeful = 70
>   Hopeless = 69

**What's *incomplete*'s number?**

Comment: Incomplete doesn't have a number $-$ it's incomplete.

Comment: @user477343 Great thinking! Sadly, not that lateral!

Comment: Hint: There's a reason I'm posting this hint in the comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is

> 93

because a word's value is

> the sum of the number of each of its distinct letters in the OP.

---

The:

> T: 14
>   H: 9
>   E: 21

Boombox:

> B: 3
>   O: 13
>   M: 8
>   X: 3
>   Note: got 27 here. Am I missing something?

Gothic:

> G: 4
>   O: 13
>   T: 14
>   H: 9
>   I: 14
>   C: 2

Hopeful:

> H: 9
>   O: 13
>   P: 5
>   E: 21
>   F: 4
>   U: 6
>   L: 12

Hopeless:

> H: 9
>   O: 13
>   P: 5
>   E: 21
>   L: 12
>   S: 9
>   69

Incomplete:

> I: 14
>   N: 4
>   C: 2
>   O: 13
>   M: 8
>   P: 5
>   L: 12
>   E: 21
>   T: 14

Comment: You're missing a B in the OP :) There's a b in out-of-the-box, two in "boombox" and one in "number". But that's it! Great job!